# How to average over colour factor for process gluon-quark scattering?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics

**My question is how to average the color factors when calculating the magnitude of amplitude for gluon-quark scattering process, for example, how to average over color factor for $|\mathcal{M}_{a}|^{2}$.** I have trouble in this exercise. But for quark-quark scattering or quark-antiquark scattering, I have known how to average over color facors. This is my note which given by the picture below,

[image]

The feynman diagrams for gluon-quark scattering are given by picture below.

[image]

The amplitudes for this three diagrams are 
$$\mathcal{M}_{a}=g^{2}\{\bar{u}(p_{c})\not{\epsilon}(p_{a})\frac{1}{\not{p}_{c}-\not{p}_{a}}u(p_{b})\not{\epsilon}^{*}(p_{d})\}\times{a^{a}a^{b*}\{C^{\dagger}(j)T^{a}T^{b}C(i)}\},$$
$$\mathcal{M}_{b}=g^{2}\{\bar{u}(p_{c})\not{\epsilon}^{*}(p_{d})\frac{1}{\not{q}}\not{\epsilon}(p_{a})u(p_{b})\}\{a^{a}a^{b*}C^{\dagger}(j)T^{b}T^{a}C(i)\},$$
$$\mathcal{M}_{c}=\frac{-f_{abc}g^{2}}{(p_{a}-p_{d})^2}\{\bar{u}(p_{c})\gamma_{\mu}u(p_{b})\epsilon^{*}(p_{d})\epsilon_{\mu}(p_{a})\}\{a^{c*}a^{a}T^{b}_{ji}V^{\mu\nu\rho}(p_{a},q,p_{d})\}$$
respectively, where $V^{\mu\nu\rho}=(p_{a}-q)^{\rho}g^{\mu\nu}+(p_{d}-q)^{\mu}g^{\nu\rho}+(-p_{d}-p_{a})^{\rho}g^{\mu\rho}$.

PS: the indexes $i,j,k=\{1,2,3\}$ denote the color $\{r,b,g\}$ and $C(i)$ is color vector. $a^{a}$, $a=1...8$ denote the color vector for gluons.

Comment: Could you perhaps state more exactly what you have problems with? Perhaps show the specific expression the you cannot calculate.

Comment: @flippiefanus For example, for $|\mathcal{M}_{a}|^{2}$, there is a color factor $a^{a}a^{b*}a^{c*t}a^{bt}\times C^{\dagger}(j)T^{a}T^{b}C(i)C^{\dagger}(i)T^{b}T^{a}C(j)$. Here, $t$ denotes the transpose. I want to average over this color factor, but I do not how to do it.